# Best way to handle Gradle boilerplate?

Tags: gradle, boilerplate

I'm using a dual boot machine. Mostly I'll be coding in Linux (Linux Mint 18.3), but occasionally in the W10 partition.

With a given Gradle project I always want the exeutables output using "installDist" to go to the same location.  I've therefore included the following lines in my build.gradle:

```
def currentOS = org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem.current()
def platform
if (currentOS.isWindows()) {
    platform = 'win'
} else if (currentOS.isLinux()) {
    platform = 'linux'
} else if (currentOS.isMacOsX()) {
    // platform = 'mac'
    throw new Exception( "not configured for Mac OS: $currentOS" )
}
else {
    throw new Exception( "attempt to run on unknown platform: $currentOS" )
}
println "OS/platform |$platform|"
String operativeDir
def homePath = System.properties['user.home']
// in W10 homePath is apparently "D:\My Documents"
// in linux homePath is "/home/mike"
// no doubt I could use java.nio.file.Path for a more elegant solution:
String pathSeparator = platform == 'linux'? '/' : '\\'
// would be better to get the My Documents path from an Env Var in Linux:
String myDoxPath = platform == 'linux'? '/media/mike/W10 D drive/My Documents' : homePath 
operativeDir = "$myDoxPath${pathSeparator}software projects${pathSeparator}operative${pathSeparator}${name}"
// get version number: must be a version.properties file at the path indicated
ConfigObject conf = new ConfigSlurper().parse( file("src/main/resources/version.properties").toURI().toURL())
version = conf.versionNumber
println "version is $version"

installDist{
    destinationDir = file( "$operativeDir/$version" )
}
```

... the thing is, all this is boilerplate: I will want to include it in every project I develop. At the moment it is cluttering up my build.gradle. What is the standard/best way to "load" this boilerplate as a module of some kind for Gradle?

Comment: Yes, the basic idea is to create your own Gradle plugin that exposes the properties you need, and include it into your build as a project dependency. I have basic experience with Gradle and found this approach on a paid tutorial. I won't post as answer because I lack experience to write correct code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ` pointed out in the comments, a custom Gradle plugin is the solution if you find yourself duplicate build logic across many projects.

You can use [Build Init Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_init_plugin.html) to generate a skeleton Gradle plugin. You'll want to install Gradle globally in order to invoke `gradle` anywhere. See the directions [here](https://gradle.org/install/) to install Gradle.

So for example, to define the `platform` property, your plugin could do the following:

```java
import org.gradle.api.GradleException;
import org.gradle.api.Project;
import org.gradle.api.Plugin;
import org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class ExamplePlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExamplePlugin.class);

    public void apply(Project project) {
        String platform = inferPlatform(project);
        project.getExtensions().getExtraProperties().set("platform", platform);
        log.info("OS/platform |{}|", platform);
    }

    private String inferPlatform(Project project) {
        // OperatingSystem is an INTERNAL package.
        // It is strongly recommended you not use internal Gradle APIs.
        OperatingSystem currentOS = OperatingSystem.current();
        if (currentOS.isWindows()) {
            return "win";
        } else if (currentOS.isLinux()) {
            return "linux";
        } else {
            throw new GradleException("unsupported OS: " + currentOS.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

I've given a Java example, but you can write your plugin in Groovy or Kotlin, too.

Once you have your plugin, simply publish it locally or to the Gradle Plugin Portal.

- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven:install
- https://guides.gradle.org/publishing-plugins-to-gradle-plugin-portal/